# Why is string comparison failing in my code?

Tags: java, string, comparison

I have an array in containing numbers that represent cable sizes (1, 1.5, 2.5, etc), stored as strings.

In my program, the array is loaded into a spinner, which is working fine.
However, when the item is selected and stored in a variable, I want to check what string was selected, and set another numerical variable to 2.5 so I can do a calculation later in the program.

I tried the following:

```
if (conductorSize = "1" ) {conCsa = 1;}
else if (conductorSize = "1.5") {conCsa = 1.5;}
```

`conductorSize` being the variable holding the selected string, and `conCsa` being the variable 
set to a numerical variable for calculation.

The compiler says that I cannot convert a string to boolean. What's happening?

Answer (score 12):

If you are doing string comparisons, use  .equals() 
Example taken from [here](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html):

```
String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT <<<<<<<<<<<<< Use this.
if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // CORRECT>
```

Comment: If you are satisfied, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the side of the question. =)

Answer (score 3):

As Ed S. points out you are using the assignment operator.  However since you are comparing a `String` you need to use the `equals` method.

```
if ("1".equals(conductorSize)) {conCsa = 1;}
else if ("1.5".equals(conductorSize)) {conCsa = 1.5;}
```

Alternatively, you could just create a new `float` from your `String`:

```
float conCsa;
try {
    conCsa = Float.parseFloat(conductorSize);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    conCsa = 0.0f; //set to a default value
}
```

Comment: Or `Double.parseDouble(conductorSize)` if a double is required/preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do might better be expressed in this way:

```
conCsa = Double.parseDouble(conductorSize);
```

Comment: Dammit, my vote limit for the day is over. I wanna upvote this answer!

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to use the .equals() method.
If performance is extremely important and you are comparing against string literals, take a look at [String.intern()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). It'll allow you to do super-fast == comparisons and avoid a full character-by-character scan as in .equals().
Performance would have to be really, really important though, to justify such a non-standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you have cable sizes which are constants, you need to use Enums , which will help you in reducing no of if condition comparisons.